# How to create a review/comment section from Firebase data In Nativescript App?

Tags: firebase, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have made an app in Nativescript Angular, this app has a section to take/upload pictures(into Fire-base) of garments

I am trying to add reviews on those pictures pulling them from the firebase. Like commenting on them

[image: nativescript-comments]

I wanted to use the [nativescript-comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-comments) code but that is in Nativescript Core XML code, and it won't fit on the nativescript angular HTML files.

I'd like to know if there's anything else i can use.

Answer (score 0):

Send comments to firebase with pictureid and commentid or what would you like.. you only need to set a relationship between pictures and comments